# How to remove a sublist from another list with Ansible

Tags: ansible

I have a list that all of its items are contained in another bigger list, and I want to remove them.

```yaml
- name: start
  set_fact:
    currently_used_ports: ["5","7","8"]

- name: Create the standard ports_list
  set_fact:
    ports_list: "{{ range(5, 10+1) | reject('search','6') | list }}"
#- debug: var=ports_list

- name: Set a list with the unused ports
  set_fact:
    available_ports: "{{ currently_used_ports | reject('search',item) | list }}"
  with_items: "{{currently_used_ports}}"
  register: out
- debug: var=out
```

I am trying to apply the `reject` and `search` filter in order to find and remove the items of the sublist but with no success.

The list I want to end with is `availabe_ports = [9,10]`

**EDIT**

I used `difference` as anmol sharma suggested but nothing happened.
However, the problem is the types of the elements in each list. If I set `currently_used_ports: [5,7,8]` ansible compares int with int and the result is correct using `difference`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ansible `difference` filter.

```
- set_fact:
    available_ports: "{{ ports_list | difference(currently_used_ports) }}"
```

For more checkout this [link](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#set-theory-filters).